# html always fetch fresh page from link

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, page-refresh

I'm setting a cookie on one page and trying to unset on the next page, which I reach via a link. However, the cookie only gets unset when I refresh the second page, F5.

For testing, I have the link and some cookie setting on the first page like this:

```
<?php
include("connect-db.php");
$id = "newuser";
setcookie("user_id", $id, time() + 31536000); 

if (isset($_COOKIE["user_id"]))
  echo "Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user_id"] . "!<br>";
else
  echo "Welcome guest!<br>";
?>
<br>
<a href='next.php'>Next</a>
```

On the next page I have this php code:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Pragma: no-cache');

setcookie("user_id", "", time()-(60*60*24), "/");
echo "<br /> Welcome " . $_COOKIE["user_id"] . "!<br>";
?>
```

How can I make sure the cookie is unset on the second page, or the page is fetched anew?

Comment: Cookies are sent along with the rest of the php headers, so the client does not get them until the request completes.  `setcookie` just sets the header; it doesn't send it to the client.

Comment: create anoher page wich only shows cookies and after loading each page try check cookies with that page. your code seems to be OK.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what you are trying to do.  If you have a dependency on the cookie on the *client*, then you may want to unset it using the client (JavaScript).  If the dependency is on the server, then it'd be tough to know what your problem is since you can just write the second part of the code to not depend on the cookie after you "unset" it.

I don't fully recommend this as it's an extra page load that's probably not necessary, but you could also force the sending of headers.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_id'])) {
    setcookie(/* your params */);
    header('Refresh: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: missing a ). but regardless, it didn't work! i guess i'll try client side then!

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the following code in second page

setcookie("user_id", "");

I hope you can solve your problem.